# Problem with creating folders on Gnome app menu on Gnome 3.8

Tags: gnome, directory

Trying to create AppFolders by dragging one icon to the next but nothing seem to work. I am running Gnome 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

This feature will be available only in the 3.10 version.
For now, you can do that : http://worldofgnome.org/how-to-create-custom-appfolders-in-gnome-shell-3-8/